# Using push in array with for...in... loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to use this code in **Javascript** to verify prime numbers using an array to store them:

```
var nprimi = [2];

function verifica(x)
{ 
var i;
var x;
var k;

 //for (k in nprimi)
 for (k=0;k<nprimi.length;k++)
    {
    if (nprimi[k]==x)
       return true;
    else if (x%nprimi[k]==0)
       return false;
    }

for (i=k+1;i<x;i++)
   {
   if (x%i==0)
      return false;
   }

 nprimi.push(x);
 return true;
 }
```

My problem is:

If I use

```
 for (k=0;k<nprimi.length;k++)
```

for loop is running correctly, but using

```
 for (k in nprimi)
```

doesn't work.

It seems that after each `nprimi.push(x)` the number of elements in objetc nprimi is always zero.

Maybe it is a very stupid error, but I am not able to find it!
Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. What do you expect, and what happens instead?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `for-in` on an array? It's for looping through the enumerable property names of an object, not the indexes of an array. More about looping arrays [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) ,it will be help you to raise your content quality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao Giancarlo,
the short answer is: in JavaScript you do not use for..in to loop through arrays.

You use for..in to loop through *objects*.

A really good explanation is to be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).

Edit:

Another thing. In your code, in the function verifica, you have an x parameter and an x local variable, you should really remove the `var x` declaration.

```
function verifica(x)
{ 
  var i;
  var x; // <-- this shouldn't be here.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because that's not what `for-in` is for. `for-in` loops through the *names of enumerable object properties*, not array indexes. Those names are strings, not numbers. So following your loop, `k+1` will be a *concatenation operation*, not an addition operation. That is, if `k` is `"2"`, then `k+1` will be `"21"`.

Don't use `for-in` to loop through arrays unless you know what you're doing and use safeguards. More about looping arrays [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Answer (score 0):

In for loop after the loop the value of k will be incremented (k++). But in the case of for-in it will not happen. So in that case you have to do it manually. I have updated the function:

```
function verifica(x)
{ 
var i;
var x;
var k;

 for (k in nprimi)
 //for (k=0;k<nprimi.length;k++)
    { 
    if (nprimi[k]==x)
       return true;
    else if (x%nprimi[k]==0)
       return false;
    }
 k++; //This is the line making difference in for-in loop
for (i=k+1;i<x;i++) {
   if (x%i==0)
      return false;
   }

 nprimi.push(x);
 return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`for in` iterates over the `indexes` of the array

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (k in myArray) {
     console.log(k + ' -> ' + myArray[k]); 
}
```

outputs:

```
 0 -> 'a'
 1 -> 'b'
 2 -> 'c'
```

As you can see, the `k` variable does not contain the `'a', 'b', 'c'`